# Drop all group rows when met a condition?

Tags: pandas, pandas-groupby, drop-duplicates

I have pandas data frame have two-level group based on '`col10`' and '`col1`'.All I want to do is, drop all group rows if a specified value in another column repeated **or this value did not existed in the group** (keep the group which the specified value existed once only) for example:

- The original data frame:

  `df = pd.DataFrame( {'col0':['A','A','A','A','A','B','B','B','B','B','B','B','c'],'col1':[1,1,2,2,2,1,1,1,1,2,2,2,1], 'col2':[1,2,1,2,3,1,2,1,2,2,2,2,1]})`

[image]

I need to keep the the rows for the group for example `(['A',1],['A',2],['B',2])` in this original DF

- The desired dataframe:

[image]

- I tried this step:

  `df.groupby(['col0','col1']).apply(lambda x: (x['col2']==1).sum()==1)`

where the result is

```
col0  col1
A     1        True
      2        True
B     1       False
      2        True
c     1       False
dtype: bool
```

How to create the desired Df based on this bool?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do this as below:

```
m=(df.groupby(['col0','col1'])['col2'].
     transform(lambda x: np.where((x.eq(1)).sum()==1,x,np.nan)).dropna().index)
df.loc[m]
```

Or:

```
df[df.groupby(['col0','col1'])['col2'].transform(lambda x: x.eq(1).sum()==1)]
```

---

```
   col0  col1  col2
0     A     1     1
1     A     1     2
2     A     2     1
3     A     2     2
4     A     2     3
12    c     1     1
```

Comment: thanks for your answer. I put this list [('A',1),('A',2),('B',2)] for illustration I don't need to specify the groups .

Comment: @Sidhom what is the condition you are looking to filter?

Comment: keep the group which the value(1) in col2 existed and did not repeated.

Comment: @Sidhom added a better solution. :)